# how can i create carousel with z-index animate

Tags: react-native, react-native-snap-carousel

I use react-native-snap-carousel and I want to have this style:

[image: My Carousel Style]

but in android z-index cannot be animated.

What should I do?

Comment: Share your code you have done for z-index

Comment: watch react-native-snap-carousel example. example 5 , 6 , 7 not work correctly on android

Comment: Are you checking with development environment or it's production environment ? Check this : *Important note regarding Android*

Comment: its not about environment check this page and read about android zIndex: https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/blob/master/doc/CUSTOM_INTERPOLATIONS.md

Comment: Ok, so have you tried adding different value then in example for zIndex ? Actually right now I don't have any working example with me.

Comment: yes. i animate elevation instead zIndex but elevation is make new problems. you can read about elevation in previous message link